# How to use which.min to extract columns?

Tags: r

```
score
       V4        V3        V5        V2        V1 
5.8602371 2.9276946 5.1799481 6.0986824 0.5405787 
which.min(score)
V1 
 5
```

Now I want to extract V1 from the dataset, such as `all_datasets$V1`. But if I use

```
all_datasets$which.min(score)
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

In my all_datasets dataset, I have 5 columns. The variable names are V1,V2...,V5. And for each column, I compute their scores in some way. Then I find the minimum score, say V1. Then I want extract the column of the dataset.

Comment: Try: `all_datasets[, which.min(score) ]`  or `all_datasets[, names(which.min(score)) ]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
min_column <- names(which.min(score))
```

would find the name for the column with the minimum score and

```
min_column_data <- all_datasets[[min_column]]
```

would extract it